# How do I specify VPC security group while creating Elastic Beanstalk environment from powershell?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to create an instance of an EB environment (`New-EBEnvironment`) using the AWS powershell tools, and I need to specify a configuration option(`Amazon.ElasticBeanstalk.Model.ConfigurationOptionSetting`) for the *VPC Security Group*, however, I can't find the option for this.

I have looked at the [Configuration Options](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options.html) (which doesnt list half of the available options) and also the [Operations:elastic-beanstalk-create-environment](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/OperationList-cmd.html#CLIReference-cmd-CreateEnvironment) reference, neither of which are helpful.
This issue is not limited to powershell, as I cant find anything for the EB-CLI either.

I've extracted all the options from an environment I created using the web console, and it is not listed here either, which is unusual.

Does anyone have any information on how I would specify this option part of the environment configuration?

[image: VPC security option]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tracked the details down. [AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-as-launchconfig.html#cfn-as-launchconfig-securitygroups) reference.

Example:

```
ResourceName: AWSEBAutoScalingLaunchConfiguration
Namespace:    aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration
OptionName:   SecurityGroups
Value:        sg-xxxxx
```